# How to implement Peek & Pop Feature of specific row of a table manually via code?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, force-touch

## Goal

I'm trying to add the peek and pop feature to my table row

---

[image]

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the `previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint)` method?  Is it called? Does it return a view controller?  What device are you testing on?  Is the collection view controller on your current VC or the detail vc?

Comment: This looks like a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46648566/341994

Comment: It seems that the error you posted is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: -1, even Apple has a proper sample app to show the implementation for peek'n'pop: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/peek_and_pop/implementing_peek_and_pop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the cell from the tableview. So the steps are as follows:

1. Get the `indexPath` using the location point from `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` method.
2. Use the `indexPath` to get cell from the `tableView`.
3. After getting the cell convert the cell frame to tableview frame.
4. Give the frame as sourceRect to `previewingContext`.

Code Below:

In **viewDidLoad**

```
if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
    registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
}
```

In Extension:

```
extension ProfileViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location), let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            previewingContext.sourceRect = tableView.convert(cell.frame, to: self.tableView)
            guard let detailViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileDetail") as? ProfileDetailViewController else {
                return nil
            }
            return detailViewController
        }
        return nil
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are not using `detailViewController` for anything other than to return it, you can get rid of the `guard` and simply do `return storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileDetail") as? ProfileDetailViewController`, which will be equivalent to your current code, but shorter and simpler

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you are not registering the cells themselves, therefore you won't get that animated border around them when they are pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I am doing that using a simple cell extension:

```
class ForceTouchCell: UITableViewCell {
    var previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing?

    func registerPreview(on controller: UIViewController, with delegate: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate) {
        self.previewingContext = controller.registerForPreviewing(with: delegate, sourceView: self)
    }

    func unregisterPreview(on controller: UIViewController) {
        guard let previewingContext = previewingContext else {
            return
        }

        controller.unregisterForPreviewing(withContext: previewingContext)
        self.previewingContext = nil
    }
}
```

Then on the controller:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        guard traitCollection.forceTouchCapability != previousTraitCollection?.forceTouchCapability else {
            return
        }

        let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells
               .compactMap { $0 as? ForceTouchCell }

        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
           visibleCells.forEach {
               $0.registerPreview(on: self, with: self)
           }
        } else {
           visibleCells.forEach {
               $0.unregisterPreview(on: self)
           }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let forceTouchCell = cell as? ForceTouchCell {
            if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
                forceTouchCell.registerPreview(on: self, with: self)
            }
         }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        if let forceTouchCell = cell as? ForceTouchCell {
            forceTouchCell.unregisterPreview(on: self)
        }
    }
}

extension MyConroller: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    func previewingContext(
    _ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint
) -> UIViewController? {
    guard
        let cell = (previewingContext.sourceView as? ForceTouchCell),
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    else {
        return nil
    }

    // use the indexPath/cell to create preview controller
}
```

The nice thing about this solution is the fact that it can be easily shared across controllers, e.g. using protocols with default implementations.